Oracle Linux 8 dnf doesn't update to newest version of file
I am trying to update the libslirp package [libslirp.x86_64 4.4.0-1.module+el8.9.+90147+a4870853] to the most recent version [libslirp-4.4.0-1.module+el8.9.0+90165+ead7974e.src.rpm].
Problem is that I cannot find the newest version with dnf/yum although it is available in the repo (looked at the official appstream repo for this).
I've tried to search for it with dnf --showduplicates list libslirp.x86_64 which only came up with verion [4.4.0-1.module+el8.9.0+90147+a4870853] and older.
Also tried dnf clean all to see if that fixes things but sadly nothing changed.
